# Index in thread handling in called function

Tags: arrays, multithreading, struct

next question:

Now I have my "car_park" with global structs.

```
struct seat {
  int size;
  int color;
};

struct car {
  int count_of_seats;
  struct seat *seats;
};

struct car_park {
  int count_of_cars;
  struct car *cars;
};
```

I read a file, malloc the necessary memory and save it into the struct(s).

Now I want to execute a function. This function should execute as 5 threads

```
func(){
  ...
}

void main(){
  struct car_park my;
  pthread_t th_read[5];

  read_current_cars(&my);  // write data from file into struct (e.g. array of 5 cars)
   while(1){
      for (i= 0; i<5; i++){
          pthread_create (&th_read[i], NULL, func, &my);
      }
   }
}
```

How can I program it, that the first thread uses the first car, the second thread uses the second car...
If I use a variable in struct car_park to increment, it doesn't work. The variable is incremented before the first thread is started.

Who can help me?

Andre

Comment: why 5 threads? what happens with the 6th car?

Comment: For the question here I take 5 cars as an example. In reality it can be more. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all cars into a queue. Synchronise queue access (wrap all queue read/write into mutex lock). make your thread `func()` to pull a car from queue and do whatever you need to do with it. There's no guarantee that thread 1 will get car 1, but to be honest I don't think it's important anyway.

Comment: I will try it with a queue... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to pass my or can you just pass a car?

If it is possible to use car as an array, you may simply rewrite your cars variable inside the car_park struct and use the number of the thread to get the car from the array (e.g. 0 for the first card, 1 for the second car etc). You may also replace your count_of_cars variable with the length of the array.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand you. (Sorry, my English is not so good.)
The car-struct is only a simply example. I have many other variables in all of my 3 structs... In the function, which I want to call as threads, I need also some variables from the struct "car_park". These are general values for the car park. So I can't give the struct "car[index]" to the thread-function. I must give "car_park" (my).
And additional: The thread-function in main is running in a while(1) loop. I edited now in the original question.